# C++ Наследование интерфейсов и реализующих их классов

Tags: c++

Представим, что у меня есть кот, который, само собой, является животным:

```
class Animal {
public:
    void walk() { std::cout << "walking..."; }
    virtual void say() const = 0;
};

class Cat : public Animal {
public:
    void say() const override { std::cout << "meow"; }
    void purr() const override { std::cout << "purr..."; }
};
```

А ещё мой кот должен уметь ходить между мирами. То есть модулями. И для этого у него должен быть интерфейс ICat, через который внешние модули его и используют. При этом внешние модули могут не знать, как работать с котами, но уметь работать с животными. А значит нужен и интерфейс IAnimal. Как бывший C# разработчик я сразу соорудил следующую систему:

```
struct IAnimal {
public:
    virtual ~IAnimal() = default;
    virtual void walk() = 0;
    virtual void say() const = 0;
};

struct ICat : public virtual IAnimal {
public:
    virtual void purr() const = 0;
};

class Animal : public virtual IAnimal {
public:
    void walk() override { std::cout << "walking..."; }
};

class Cat : public Animal, public ICat {
public:
    void say() const override { std::cout << "meow"; }
    void purr() const override { std::cout << "purr..."; }
};
```

Моему разочарованию не было предела, когда в ответ я увидел warning:

```
warning C4250: 'Cat' : inherits 'Animal::Animal::walk' via dominance.
```

Первый вариант, который приходит в голову: поскольку компилятор банально не понимает, что я ни за что не начну переопределять walk в ICat (ведь ICat - это всего-лишь безвольный интерфейс), то можно попросту поставить #pragma warning. И всё.

Ещё вариант, можно убрать наследование ICat от IAnimal. Это уберёт warning, но тогда придётся делать бесконечные касты ICat к IAnimal. При этом глядя на доступное извне описание интерфейса ICat, совершенно не очевидным является, что он может быть приведён к IAnimal. И да, сейчас это очевидно из понятий кота и животного. В реальной же ситуации, со сложными иерархиями, такой понятности можно не ждать.

Можно "подсказать" о наличии такого каста, добавлением метода IAnimal ICat::asAnimal(). Это решает большинство вопросов, но до C#-повской простоты и понятности тут очень далеко.

Собственно вопрос: как это сделать правильно в C++?

Comment: Может виртуальное наследование.

Comment: А вообще возможно стоит использовать агрегацию, а не наследование.

Comment: Вообще не очень понятно, зачем отдельно Animal и IAnimal, как и отдельные Cat и  ICat. IMHO, конечно... Почему внешние модули не могут работать с котом, как с котом (или животным)? Такое ощущение, что это просто попытка эмулировать интерфейсы C# в С++, которому они, скажем мягко, не свойственны...

Comment: Может в `Animal::walk` добавить `override`?

Comment: Да у вас вообще тут `;` не хватает! Приведите код в формате [mcve], чтобы можно было получить упомянутое предупреждение.

Comment: В конце-концов это просто warning - на случай, если хотели не этого. Голосую за первый вариант.

Comment: Ваша ошибка в том, что Вы пытаетесь писать на C# в терминах C++. Раз выбрали C++, то и пишите на нём — тут нет интерфейсов. В частности, разделение `IAnimal` и `Animal` это ограничение C#, а не его достоинство. В C++ это должен быть один класс.

Comment: Что-то в моём gcc никаких warnings :(

Comment: А ещё -  у вас все конкретные методы - приватные...

Comment: Прошу прощения за ошибки в примере, писал "из головы". Всё исправил в компилируемый вид.

Comment: Причина использования интерфейсов - это классическая модульность в C++. Реализация кота спрятана в .dll-файле. Использовать его могут внешние модули, не обязательно написанные на той-же версии C++, что и кот. Реализовать взаимодействие с такими иначе чем, через интрерфейсы... Только разве что через чистый extern "C"

Comment: Виртуальное наследование тут уже есть. Если бы не оно, пример был бы не рабочим вообще.

Comment: А чем отличается "использование интерфейсов" от "использования классов"? Ведь у IAnimal будут точно такие же "декорированные" имена, что и у Animal... Лично я не вижу никакой необходимости в абстрактном IСat - мне кажется, что абстрактного Animal и конкретного Cat более чем достаточно. Кстати, "разные версии С++" могут по-разному реализовывать множественное наследование, так что проблема взаимодействия останется.

Comment: Не совсем так. dll в таблице экспорта будет содержать вообще только 2 метода: CreateCat и FreeCat. Первый возвращает указатель на созданный ICat, а второй очищает память для ICat. Методы walk, say, purr будут вызываться через таблицу виртуальных методов: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2

И профит подобного подхода в том, что таблица работает одинаково, и для MSVC 2017 и для C++ 6.0 и для MinGW gcc 5.2.0

Comment: Чем в этом контексте отличаются Cat и ICat?

Comment: Cat содержит реализацию. ICat - нет.

Comment: Более детальное объяснение:
Мой модуль (моя dll) содержит реализацию say, purr и walk. Эта реализация сложна, и может ещё и является коммерческой тайной. Собственно иначе как на скомпилированный вид онной клиенты смотреть не должны. Да и не зачем это им. Ведь код уже скомпонован в dll-файле. Если бы я этот код экспортировал "просто так", то у меня dll оказалась бы полна декорированными именами всех этих методов. Это не так уж и плохо, при условии что и кот и его клиенты собираются на одной и той-же версии компилятора. Но если это не так, то формат декорированных имён будет не совпадать

Comment: И в чем разница? Та же таблица виртуальных функций. Только и того, что в ICat в ней, грубо говоря, прописаны нули... Более того, ICat создать невозможно - он абстрактный.

Comment: Поэтому я использую интрерфейсы, ведь когда я их использую, то клиент моей dll-ки смотрит на .h файл, видит описание ICat, и сразу узнаёт, что по адресу указателя на ICat на первом же месте лежит указатель на таблицу виртуальных функций. У cat-а 4 метода (деструктор тоже метод), и все они лежат в определённом порядке. Так что 3-я запись в таблице виртуальных функций - это метод say. всё что остаётся клиенту, так это вызвать метод по адресу, на который указывает 3-я запись данной таблицы, передав ему указатель на ICat в качестве аргумента. И будет произведён вызов say.

Comment: Напрямую создавать в условиях кроссмодульности объекты тоже нельзя. Даже нельзя использовать delete cat из внешней системы. Посему для создания кота и для его очистки используются экспортируемые extern "C" методы CreateCat и FreeCat.

Comment: Ну а так он будет смотреть на все то же самое для Cat. Ладно, мы говорим на совершенно разных языках (C# vs С++), так что никак не можем понять друг друга... Возможно, я чего-то недопонимаю, но тогда пусть те, что в C++ лучше разбираются, пояснят...

Comment: Чтобы не плодить оффтоп, можете почитать эту статью: http://www.cyberguru.ru/cpp/cpp-exporting-cpp-classes-from-dll.html?showall=1 Тут как раз описано, почему нужно использовать данный подход на C++. Кстати, в C# как раз использование интерфейсов и не является обязательным. Они становятся очень полезными для модульного тестирования и для S.O.L.I.D. Но для кроссмодульности не нужны

Comment: @AlexeyMakarenya, всё, что Вы тут описываете никаким образом не запрещает реализации находится в том же `ICat`. **Никаким.** От того, что там будет находится реализация методов не изменится ровным счётом ничего.

Comment: Пошёл учить матчасть ))) Всё верно

Comment: на сайте майкрософта описывается эта проблема, ее причины и лечения https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6b3sy7ae.aspx

Comment: Вспомнил. Интерфейсы используются для того, чтобы скрыть не только реализацию Cat, но и её структуру. То есть чтобы в заголовочном файне не пришлось описывать все поля, содержащиеся в Cat. ICat же полей не содержит. Можно это сделать при помощи форвард декларации какого-нибудь CatImpl. Это второй способ, но он более сложный, так как приходится делать обёртки всем методам.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68581/discussion-on-question-by-alexey-makarenya-c----).

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что наследование в C++ не такое, как в C#. В частности, понятия «интерфейс» там вовсе нет, и вам пришлось эмулировать его при помощи множественного наследования.

Таким образом, у вас действительно `walk` наследуется по двум путям. В случае, когда один из классов-предков (в вашем случае `ICat`) не перекрывает `walk`, то компилятор может «самостоятельно» выбрать реализацию в `Cat`. Но тем не менее, компилятор Visual Studio честно предупреждает о возможных проблемах (о них [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190971/276994) и немного [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7071695/276994)), которые лежат не в плоскости кода, а в плоскости «ожидаемого» поведения. В вашем случае (эмуляция интерфейсов) эти проблемы не возникнут.

Так что просто подавите это предупреждение (через `#pragma warning`) и программируйте дальше.

---

Кстати, gcc ваш код компилирует без предупреждений.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, если код работает в разных модулях, то спрячьте деструктор интерфейса и никому его не показывайте.

```
struct IAnimal {
    virtual void walk() = 0;
    virtual void say() const = 0;
protected:
    virtual ~IAnimal() = default;
};
```

Виртуальный деструктор нужен чтобы можно было написать

```
IAnimal* a = ...;
delete a;
```

Но Вы не можете так делать, т.к. `delete` должен вызываться только в том модуле, где создали объект (иначе всё сломается когда модули будут использовать разные версии рантайма языка).

---

Во-вторых в С++ такие интерфейсы не нужны. Всё будет работать без них.
И виртуальные функции не нужны, но их можно использовать как замену dllexport/dllimport.

```
// Foo.hpp
class Foo {
public:
  using UniqueFoo = unique_ptr<Foo, void(*)(Foo*)>;
  static LIB_EXPORT UniqueFoo create();

  virtual Bar* add(const char* key);
  virtual void remove(const char* key);
private:
  Foo() = default;
  ~Foo() = default;
  std::map<string, unique_ptr<Bar>> m_;
};

// Foo.cpp
auto Foo::create() -> UniqueFoo {
  return {new Foo, [](Foo* p){ delete p; }};
}
Bar* Foo::add(const char* key) {
  m_.emplace(key, make_unique<Bar>())->second.get();
}
void Foo::remove(const char* key) { m_.erase(key); }
```

Что может пойти не так? Ничего, если не передавать между модулями типы, реализация которых может отличаться.

Реализация `delete` может быть разной - значит передаем `unique_ptr` со своим делетером.

`unique_ptr` прост как пробка, его можно передать как есть.

`std::string` может отличаться - значит передаем `const char*`.

`std::map` может отличаться - но он член класса и мы его никуда не передаем.

У класса может быть разный `sizeof`? Ну и ладно, он у нас создается фабрикой.

Comment: «С++ такие интерфейсы не нужны. Всё будет работать без них.» — ну, в C# тоже работает и без них, там нет проблемы бинарной несовместимости рантаймов. Думаю, ТС решает не техническую проблему, а организационную: класс _должен_ быть виден только через интерфейс, чтобы клиенты не писали код, зависимый от конкретной имплементации.

Comment: Ну, а как тестировать без интерфейсов? Ну и не вполне карго-культ: я часто сталкивался с тем, что клиенты кода используют открытые функции, специфичные для класса, и им же потом сложно переписать код, когда этот класс заменяется другим. Я скорее представляю себе иерархию классов у ТС как `IVehicle : ICar : Ferrari`, и хочется заставить клиентов не использовать Ferrari-специфичные функции.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ICat : public virtual IAnimal
```

Зачем здесь виртуальность? Интерфейсы не несут реализаций, поэтому делить им вроде как нечего. (*Непонятен смысл деструктора в `IAnimal`, ибо это уже относится к тонкостям реализации, т.е. иерархии `Animal`.*) Тогда и компилятор поверит, что это чисто виртуальные классы (интерфейсы по-вашему), а не что-то странное абстрактное.

Comment: базовый класс (IAnimals/Animals) должен иметь виртуальный деструктор во избежания проблем в будущем.

Comment: @KoVadim, ну так класс и должен иметь, а интерфейс - нет.

Comment: только в с++ нет интерфейсов, поэтому IAnimal должен иметь виртуальный деструктор

Comment: Деструктор IAnimal - это тонкости реализации C++. Для любой иерархии с полиморфизмом, невиртуальные деструкторы - это настоящее минное поле из граблей. Если же деструктор самого верхнего объекта в иерархии сделать виртуальным - это гарантирует виртуальность всех остальных деструкторов даже тога, когда программисты забудут ключевое слово "virtual". Удобно и практично, да и ReSharper настоятельно рекомендует.

Comment: @AlexeyMakarenya, следуя идеологии интерфейсов, сроком их жизни управляет (создает и прибивает) кто-то извне, кто в курсе истинного типа объекта, со всей его виртуальностью цепочки наследования.

Comment: Хуже от использования подобного виртуального деструктора не становиться никому, а корректность работы всех унаследованных от него классов он гарантирует. То есть избавляет от ошибок в остальном коде.

Comment: @AlexeyMakarenya, ваши интерфейсы начинают навязывать стратегию управления циклом жизни объектов. Что ж, говорят, фортрановые можно программы можно писать на любом языке (=

Comment: Ребята из JetBrains со мной согласны ;) Ну то есть я вообще начал как изучать эту тему, да и использовать данный подход после того, как мне настоятельно начал предлагать это ReSharper. Тем более что: данное описание ничего не навязывает использующему интерфейс коду, а реализующему коду оно навязывает безошибочный и единственно правильный способ определения деструктора в данном случае.

Comment: @AlexeyMakarenya, ребята из джетбрейнса за вас код не пишут, во вред [можно использовать самое милое и пушистое](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0). В С++ принято не платить за то, что не используешь. `IAnimal` вряд ли будет иметь альтернативного наследника.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68541/discussion-between-alexey-makarenya-and-free-ze).

Comment: _"сроком их жизни управляет (создает и прибивает) кто-то извне, кто в курсе истинного типа объекта"_ - он вполне может сразу скастить к интерфейсу и пользоваться только им. Вот тогда и должен понадобиться виртуальный деструктор у интерфейса.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а может и не кастить, ибо все равно нужно иметь дело с реализаией.